# run script on elements that have been loaded into page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading the top navigation via jQuery:

```
<script> 
    $(function(){
        $("#top-nav").load("top-nav.html");
    });
</script>
```

that will load something like this:

```
<ul class="list-inline text-center navigation">
    <li>
        <a href="one.html">
            one
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="two.html">
            two
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="three.html">
            three
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That is working great. I am now trying to make the active link underlined, with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var url = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('ul a').each(function() {
            if(jQuery(this).attr('href') === url) {
                jQuery(this).parent().addClass('underline-nav');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, it does not work, because it cannot find one.html, two.html, three.html. I know this because if I paste the contents of top-nav.html into the body, instead of loading it, this works great.

**Here is my question:** How do I run a script on elements that are loaded into the page?

Thanks.

Comment: Execute it in the callback function of `.load`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code.

```
<script> 
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
    $("#top-nav").load("top-nav.html", function(){

    jQuery('ul a').each(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).attr('href') === url) {
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass('underline-nav');
        }

   });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `complete` callback function of `load` to ensure it's loaded.

```
$("#top-nav").load("top-nav.html", function(){
    //check the loaded elements
});
```

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.